# WOWZA Streaming Server Bandwidth consumption monitoring for specific app/folder

Tags: video-streaming, bandwidth, wowza, web-analytics

I am new to WOWZA streaming server

- Have created new VoD application "voddemo" which generate streaming URL for video content of "voddemo" folder placed inside "content" directory of WOWZA app folder (aka 'Application-specific directory')
- Looking to know a way to obtain total Streaming bandwidth consumption from directory of "voddemo"
- Which will be used for video analytic purpose

Comment: FWIW: There's a monitoring page in the manager that might provide the data you are looking for.  Assuming a VOD application named "vod", the URL is http://localhost:8088/enginemanager/Home.htm#application/_defaultVHost_/vod/vod/monitoring

Comment: Thank for response Orde , As of the requirement we are looking for is to obtain total bandwidth streamed form this specific application. But UI is providing graph of throughput only. We need total bandwidth consumed by application in a month

Answer (score 3):

There's several ways you can get statistics info on a Wowza streaming application.

1. As orde pointed out above, you can use the Monitoring page from the Manager UI. This page can be reached by selecting the application page, and clicking on Monitoring from the left content menu. You can view Network usage on a historical basis as well.
2. You can use the built-in HTTPProvider for connectioncounts (http://localhost:8086/connectioncounts). It shows an XML snapshot of the current connection info. You can see the network usage for a particular application by checking the MessagesOutBytesRate value.
   `<MessagesOutBytesRate>139055.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>`
3. You can create your own HTTPProvider by developing a custom module based on the Wowza Java API.

   ```
   package com.wowza.wms.http;

   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.net.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.application.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.client.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.logging.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.server.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.vhost.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.http.*;
   import com.wowza.util.*;
   import com.wowza.wms.httpstreamer.model.*;
   //import org.json.*;

   public class HTTPConnectionCountsXML extends HTTProvider2Base
   {   class MyCounter
       {
           int total = 0;
       }
       private void outputConnectionInfo(StringBuffer ret, ConnectionCounter counter)
       {
           ret.append(""+counter.getCurrent()+"");
           ret.append(""+counter.getTotal()+"");
           ret.append(""+counter.getTotalAccepted()+"");
           ret.append(""+counter.getTotalRejected()+"");
       }
           private void outputIOPerformanceInfo(StringBuffer ret, IOPerformanceCounter ioPerformance)
       {
           ret.append(""+ioPerformance.getMessagesInBytesRate()+"");
           ret.append(""+ioPerformance.getMessagesOutBytesRate()+"");
       }
           private int toCount(Integer intObj, MyCounter counter)
       {
           int ret = intObj==null?0:intObj.intValue();
           counter.total += ret;
           return ret;
       }
       public void onHTTPRequest(IVHost inVhost, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp)
       {
           if (!doHTTPAuthentication(inVhost, req, resp))
               return;
           StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer();

       String queryStr = req.getQueryString();
       Map<String, String> queryMap = HTTPUtils.splitQueryStr(queryStr);
       boolean isFlat = false;
       isFlat = this.properties.getPropertyBoolean("isFlat", isFlat);
       if (queryMap.containsKey("flat"))
           isFlat = true;
       try
       {
           List<String> vhostNames = VHostSingleton.getVHostNames();
           ret.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<WowzaMediaServer>");

           IServer server = Server.getInstance();
           if (!isFlat)
           {
               outputConnectionInfo(ret, server.getConnectionCounter());
               outputIOPerformanceInfo(ret, server.getIoPerformanceCounter());
           }
           Iterator<String> iter = vhostNames.iterator();
           while (iter.hasNext())
           {
               String vhostName = iter.next();
               IVHost vhost = (IVHost)VHostSingleton.getInstance(vhostName);
               if (vhost != null)
               {
                   if (!isFlat)
                   {
                       ret.append("<VHost>");
                       ret.append("<Name>"+URLEncoder.encode(vhostName, "UTF-8")+"</Name>");
                       ret.append("<TimeRunning>"+vhost.getTimeRunningSeconds()+"</TimeRunning>");
                       ret.append("<ConnectionsLimit>"+vhost.getConnectionLimit()+"</ConnectionsLimit>");
                       outputConnectionInfo(ret, vhost.getConnectionCounter());
                       outputIOPerformanceInfo(ret, vhost.getIoPerformanceCounter());
                   }
                   List<String> appNames = vhost.getApplicationNames();
                   Iterator<String> appNameIterator = appNames.iterator();
                   while (appNameIterator.hasNext())
                   {
                       String applicationName = appNameIterator.next();
                       IApplication application = vhost.getApplication(applicationName);
                       if (application == null)
                           continue;
                       if (!isFlat)
                       {
                           ret.append("<Application>");
                           ret.append("<Name>"+URLEncoder.encode(applicationName, "UTF-8")+"</Name>");
                           ret.append("<Status>loaded</Status>");
                           ret.append("<TimeRunning>"+application.getTimeRunningSeconds()+"</TimeRunning>");

                           outputConnectionInfo(ret, application.getConnectionCounter());
                           outputIOPerformanceInfo(ret, application.getIoPerformanceCounter());
                       }
                       List<String> appInstances = application.getAppInstanceNames();
                       Iterator<String> iterAppInstances = appInstances.iterator();
                       while (iterAppInstances.hasNext())
                       {
                           String appInstanceName = iterAppInstances.next();
                           IApplicationInstance appInstance = application.getAppInstance(appInstanceName);
                           if (appInstance == null)
                               continue;

                           if (!isFlat)
                           {
                               ret.append("<ApplicationInstance>");
                               ret.append("<Name>"+URLEncoder.encode(appInstance.getName(), "UTF-8")+"</Name>");
                               ret.append("<TimeRunning>"+appInstance.getTimeRunningSeconds()+"</TimeRunning>");

                               outputConnectionInfo(ret, appInstance.getConnectionCounter());
                               outputIOPerformanceInfo(ret, appInstance.getIOPerformanceCounter());
                           }
                           Map<String, Integer> flashCounts = appInstance.getPlayStreamCountsByName();
                           Map<String, Integer> smoothCounts = appInstance.getHTTPStreamerSessionCountsByName(IHTTPStreamerSession.SESSIONPROTOCOL_SMOOTHSTREAMING);
                           Map<String, Integer> cupertinoCounts = appInstance.getHTTPStreamerSessionCountsByName(IHTTPStreamerSession.SESSIONPROTOCOL_CUPERTINOSTREAMING);
                           Map<String, Integer> sanjoseCounts = appInstance.getHTTPStreamerSessionCountsByName(IHTTPStreamerSession.SESSIONPROTOCOL_SANJOSESTREAMING);
                           Map<String, Integer> rtspCounts = appInstance.getRTPSessionCountsByName();
                           Map<String, Integer> mpegdashCounts = appInstance.getHTTPStreamerSessionCountsByName(IHTTPStreamerSession.SESSIONPROTOCOL_MPEGDASHSTREAMING);
                           List<String> publishStreams = appInstance.getStreams().getPublishStreamNames();
                           Set<String> streamNames = new HashSet<String>();
                           streamNames.addAll(publishStreams);
                           streamNames.addAll(flashCounts.keySet());
                           streamNames.addAll(smoothCounts.keySet());
                           streamNames.addAll(cupertinoCounts.keySet());
                           streamNames.addAll(sanjoseCounts.keySet());
                           streamNames.addAll(rtspCounts.keySet());
                           streamNames.addAll(mpegdashCounts.keySet());
                           Iterator<String> siter = streamNames.iterator();
                           while(siter.hasNext())
                           {
                               String streamName = siter.next();
                               MyCounter counter = new MyCounter();
                               if (isFlat)
                               {
                                   int flashCount = toCount(flashCounts.get(streamName), counter);
                                   int cupertinoCount = toCount(cupertinoCounts.get(streamName), counter);
                                   int smoothCount = toCount(smoothCounts.get(streamName), counter);
                                   int sanjoseCount = toCount(sanjoseCounts.get(streamName), counter);
                                   int rtspCount = toCount(rtspCounts.get(streamName), counter);
                                   int mpegdashCount = toCount(mpegdashCounts.get(streamName), counter);
                                   ret.append("<Stream ");
                                   ret.append("vhostName=\""+URLEncoder.encode(vhostName, "UTF-8")+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("applicationName=\""+URLEncoder.encode(applicationName, "UTF-8")+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("appInstanceName=\""+URLEncoder.encode(appInstanceName, "UTF-8")+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("streamName=\""+URLEncoder.encode(streamName, "UTF-8")+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsFlash=\""+flashCount+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsCupertino=\""+cupertinoCount+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsSanJose=\""+sanjoseCount+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsSmooth=\""+smoothCount+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsRTSP=\""+rtspCount+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsMPEGDash=\""+mpegdashCount+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("sessionsTotal=\""+counter.total+"\" ");
                                   ret.append("/>");
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ret.append("<Stream>");
                                   ret.append("<Name>"+URLEncoder.encode(streamName, "UTF-8")+"</Name>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsFlash>"+toCount(flashCounts.get(streamName), counter)+"</SessionsFlash>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsCupertino>"+toCount(cupertinoCounts.get(streamName), counter)+"</SessionsCupertino>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsSanJose>"+toCount(sanjoseCounts.get(streamName), counter)+"</SessionsSanJose>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsSmooth>"+toCount(smoothCounts.get(streamName), counter)+"</SessionsSmooth>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsRTSP>"+toCount(rtspCounts.get(streamName), counter)+"</SessionsRTSP>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsMPEGDash>" + toCount(mpegdashCounts.get(streamName), counter) + "</SessionsMPEGDash>");
                                   ret.append("<SessionsTotal>"+counter.total+"</SessionsTotal>");
                                   ret.append("</Stream>");
                               }
                           }

                           if (!isFlat)
                               ret.append("</ApplicationInstance>");
                       }
                       if (!isFlat)
                           ret.append("</Application>");
                   }
                   if (!isFlat)
                       ret.append("</VHost>");
               }
           }
           ret.append("</WowzaMediaServer>");
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(HTTPServerVersion.class).error("HTTPServerInfoXML.onHTTPRequest: "+e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try
       {
           resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
           OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
           byte[] outBytes = ret.toString().getBytes();
           out.write(outBytes);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(HTTPServerVersion.class).error("HTTPServerInfoXML.onHTTPRequest: "+e.toString());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }


   }
   ```
4. You can use the REST API (for version 4.3+) to query via cURL or other HTTP request method. One example is to query historical data for a given application.

   ```
   curl -X GET --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive/monitoring/historic
   ```

   This will return data with the following data array values:

   index 0 = Bandwidth Usage coming into the application in KB/s
   index 1 = Bandwidth Usage going out of the application in KB/s
   index 2 = RTMP Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 3 = RTSP Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 4 = HDS Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 5 = HLS Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 6 = SmoothStreaming Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 7 = WEB RTC Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 8 = WEM Connection Count in and out of the application 
   index 9 = DASH Connection Count in and out of the application
5. You can also use the Wowza Google Analytics module, which lets you integrate your GA account with your Wowza streaming data.

Comment: Thank for response Michelle-B  , As of the requirement we are looking for is to obtain total bandwidth streamed form this specific application. But UI is providing graph of throughput.

Comment: We need analytics of total bandwidth consumed by application in a month

Comment: @BharathSN the Manager UI should have a date/time range selection (including for "last 30 days") for the Network graph, which shows both "Bits In" and Bits Out" data points. You can also integrate the different stat collection methods with a database system, so that you can easily run data mining reports. For example, you can run a scheduled crontab task that queries the XML snapshot stats every half hour, and dump that data into a staging database table.

Comment: how to get consumed data by push stream. can we get it?

Comment: You can look into the IOPerformanceCounter interface in the Java API, and have a custom module that logs these data for you.

Comment: When I tried api way (v2/servers/{serverName}/vhosts/{vhostName}/applications/vod/monitoring/historic), api returns data divided into hour groups. But I couldn't make sense data part, it is 10 lengthed array, I see just data[1] item increasing and also decreasing. How should we understand data?

Comment: @Bilal I have edited my answer above to include the descriptions for each data element

Comment: Thanks for descriptions. But there are just average, max and min values. That's why I saw value was decreasing, it was average value. 

What about total outgoing bandwidth? How can I get this from API?